# Export csv file to download from mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get csv file from my mysql db and sent it to the browser for download.

I read some posts about it but I cant get the file downloaded.

When I run my code the file is not downloaded.

I send POST through ajax to this file.

Here is my Code :

```
<?php

    download_send_headers();

    $mysqli = new mysqli(*****);

    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

    $sql = "SELECT trainer, COUNT(trainer) FROM personal_traning WHERE gym = ? GROUP BY trainer"; 

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['gym']);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();

    $stmt->bind_result($trainer, $trainerCount);

    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 

    $results = array();

    $row = array();

    $row[0] = "Trainer name";
    $row[1] = "Count";

    fputcsv($f, $row); 

    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {

    $row = array();

    $row[0] = $trainer;
    $row[1] = $trainerCount;

    fputcsv($f, $row); 

    }

    $output = stream_get_contents($f);

    fclose($f);

    echo $output;

    die();

function download_send_headers() {

    header('Content-Disposition: attachement;filename="name";');

    header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8');
}


?>
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add .csv to the filename of the header.